# Simplification with assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, assumptions

I'm trying to make Mathematica do some simplifications for me. I have the expression

```
((1 + s[1]) (-1 + s[2]) )/(-1 + s[1] s[2])
```

and want to simplify this with the assumption that

```
s[1]^2==1
```

(it should simplify to 1+s[1], as can be verified manually)

I obviously tried

```
Simplify[((1 + s[1]) (-1 + s[2]) )/(-1 + s[1] s[2]), s[1]^2 == 1]
```

to no avail. Is there any way I can persuade Mathematica to do this for me?

Edit:

Here's the manual simplification:

$$
\frac{(1 + s[1]) (-1 + s[2])}{-1 + s[1] s[2]}=\frac{(1 + s[1])(-1+s[1]^{-1})(-1+s[1]s[2])+(-1+s[1]^{-1})+(-1+s[1]s[2]) }{-1 + s[1] s[2]}=\frac{(1 + s[1])((-1+s[1])(-1+s[1]s[2])+(-1+s[1])+(-1+s[1]s[2]))}{-1 + s[1] s[2]}=\frac{(1 + s[1])((-1+s[1])(-1+s[1]s[2])+(-1+s[1])+(-1+s[1]s[2]))}{-1 + s[1] s[2]}=\frac{(1 + s[1])(-1+s[1])((-1+s[1]s[2])+1)+(1+s[1])(-1+s[1]s[2])}{-1 + s[1] s[2]}=\frac{0((-1+s[1]s[2])+1)+(1+s[1])(-1+s[1]s[2])}{-1 + s[1] s[2]}=1+s[1]
$$

Comment: Since there is no `s[1]^2` in the expression it can't be simplified. You can do `c /. Solve[((1 + s[1]) (-1 + s[2]))/(-1 + s[1] s[2]) == c && 
   s[1]^2 == 1, c, MaxExtraConditions -> All]` or `Cancel[((1 + s[1]) (-1 + s[2]))/(-1 + 
     s[1] s[2]) /. {{s[1] -> -1}, {s[1] -> 1}}]` or `Simplify[((1 + s[1]) (-1 + s[2]))/(-1 + s[1] s[2]), 
   s[1] == #] & /@ {-1, 1}`.

Comment: What's to select that version, though, from $s[1]+s[1]^2$, or indeed $1+1/s[1]$? It's not a particularly well-defined problem.

Comment: @episanty You can simplify it manually, as I showed in the edit.

Comment: @Tom I don't see that that's the case. For me it simplifies to $s[1]+s[1]^2$. There must be something wrong with your workings. (... or, the problem is not well defined.)

Comment: @episanty If $s[1]^2=1$, then $s[1]+s[1]^2==s[1]+1$, so we get the same answer

Answer (score 1):

[`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Simplify.html) has built-in support for the [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Assumptions.html) option. Thus, for example,

```
Simplify[Sqrt[x^2]]
```

will return the same argument, since the real part of `x` could be negative, then it can simplify it further:

```
Simplify[Sqrt[x^2], Assumptions -> x > 0]
```

returns `x`.

---

In your case, though, there is no ready simplification because there's no real need to call `s[1]^2`. On the other hand, one can see that your assumption severely restricts the values `s[1]` can take. I would advise you to see this in the light of "`s[1]` must satisfy this given equation": you can then `Solve` it and see what happens to your expression when you substitute in the values. Thus,

```
((1 + s[1]) (-1 + s[2]))/(-1 + s[1] s[2]) /. Solve[s[1]^2 == 1, s[1]]
```

returns `{0,2}`, which is what I believe you were expecting. If your expression gets more complicated, you may need to bring in a further `Simplify` step enveloping the substitution.

Comment: That's not quite what I want - I don't want to fix the value of s[1], I just want it to be a symbol whose square is 1. With just this assumption (not setting s[1] to be equal to +1 or -1) one can (manually) reduce the expression to 1+s[1].

Comment: Can you do it manually, though, without doing a case-by-case analysis? Otherwise, an equally compelling case might be made that under that restriction your expression equals `(1+s[1])^2/2`. How is the code to know what expression to simplify this to?

Comment: You can do it manually by writing (-1+s[2])=(-1+s[1]^(-1))(-1+s[1]s[2])+(-1+s[1]^(-1))+(-1+s[1]s[2]) and then expanding the numerator.

Comment: Apologies, but I don't follow those maths. Are you sure they are correct? It would help if you included in your question a LaTeX'd version of the manual simplification you are hoping Mathematica can do.

Comment: Sorry for being brief yesterday, I was on my phone. Please see the edit for the maths

Answer (score 0):

```
   (((1 + s[1]) (-1 + s[2]))/(-1 + s[1] s[2]) // Expand) /. 
  s[1] -> 1 // Simplify

(*   2    *)

    (((1 + s[1]) (-1 + s[2]))/(-1 + s[1] s[2]) // Expand) /. 
  s[1] -> -1 // Simplify

(*  0   *)
```

Have fun.

Comment: I don't want to treat s[1] as a number, just a symbol whose square is 1

Comment: @Tom If there is something whose square is 1, one concludes that something is either 1, or -1. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Only if you assume that s[1] is a complex number - I want to just treat it as a symbol